React Native Gradle Build failure: Cannot sync project due to Kotlin binary version metadata
I am getting this error when trying to sync my android studio project built with react native
/Users/ronaldjones/.gradle/caches/8.12/generated-gradle-jars/gradle-api-8.12.jar!/META-INF/declarative-dsl-core.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
Online everything simply says to update my Kotlin version, which I have done in my build.gradle, settings.gralde and currently both
BELOW ARE MY FILES
build.gradle
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 25
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33
        kotlin_version = "2.0.0"
        // We use NDK 23 which has both M1 support and is the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
        ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.4")
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.2'
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
   google()
    mavenLocal()
   mavenCentral()
    maven {
      // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
      url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
    }
   maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
  }
}

settings.gradle

plugins {
id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.9.10" apply false
}

rootProject.name = 'ATHApp'
apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)
include ':app'
includeBuild('../node_modules/@react-native/gradle-plugin')
include ':@react-native-firebase_auth'
project(':@react-native-firebase_auth').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, './../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/auth/android')
include ':react-native-gesture-handler'
project(':react-native-gesture-handler').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android')
include ':react-native-push-notification'
project(':react-native-push-notification').projectDir = file('../node_modules/react-native-push-notification/android')


grade-wrapper.properties
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.12-all.zip
networkTimeout=10000
validateDistributionUrl=true
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists


Your settings.gradle has a Kotlin version in it (1.9.10) which should be upgraded... although I can't imagine applying the Android plugin in settings.gradle has any use so you should probably just remove the plugins block there entirely. Also, you   will have further subproject build.gradle files which you need to examine for Kotlin versions/application of the Kotlin plugins
